# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf without JS

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

prehistory:
I want to develop web app using java web framework.
As backend i've chosen Spring MVC. As template engine Thymeleaf was chosen.

The question is: is it possible to develop an app, including async requests, without using javascript.

Thanks guys.

**EDIT:**
How about [Asynchronous Request Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async)?

Comment: The async part of Spring (Servlet-spec 3) allows you to keep sending data to the client after you have received the request. it is almost always used to generate data that is processed using JavaScript. If you used it for server side rendering you would keep adding to the bottom of the page, so the page would keep growing in length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. Thymeleaf, Velocity, JSP, JSF are all server side rendering, which means that you need re-generate the entire page if you want to change anything.

Also if you don't have JavaScript, the only requests you can make from the browser are form POSTs (multipart, or form-encoded) or GET requests when links are clicked.

It is possible to change a smaller part of the page if you use frames or iframes, but that is in no way recommended (I should not even write about it).

If you are building an app, I don't think there is any way around using JavaScript, but if you choose a good framework like Angular, even a backend developer (like myself) can build smaller async web applications.

Comment: I'm trying to make it pure java style. Can you recommend something?

Comment: What is you runtime, is it a browser app, web on mobile, or IOS/Android.

Comment: If you use google maps, you will have to use JavaScript, there is no way around that!

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous web requests rely on javascript to work. You're not going to get very far trying to build a web application without javascript